# mean from array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean

I have 10 of `(1000,)` shaped arrays and I am trying to calculate mean for the first element across all the 10 arrays.
When I print `array_name[20]`, the 10th element of each array gets printed and I see the below output:

```
1 2 5 6 ...
```

However, when I do `np.mean(array_name[20])`, I see the same values printed again but now in float format as

```
1.0 2.0 5.0 6.0 ...
```

How do I calculate the column wise mean in this case?

Comment: `np.average(list_of_arrays, axis=0)`.

Comment: `np.mean` has an optional `axis` argument that you need for this case

Comment: I already tried axis=0 but even that doesn't work. 
When I try print(type(array_name)) the output is 
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: What is the shape of your `array_name`? is it a single 2-D array or do you have a group of separate arrays?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If your `array_name` is of shape `(10,1000)`:

```
array_name.mean(0)
```

If you have a list of separate arrays, each with shape `(1000,)`:

```
np.stack(list_of_arrays).mean(0)
```

A toy example:

```
X = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,4))
#[[4 3 0 9]
# [8 3 0 1]
# [6 6 6 1]]
X.mean(0)
#[6.         4.         2.         3.66666667]
```